# Java Using the Replace Method repeatedly

Tags: java

I have to write a program in Java that replaces letters in 'Hello, World' by switching the letters 'e' and 'o' so the output of the program would be 
"Holle, Werld".  I have attempted to do this with the following code, but have realized that all of the o's are e's and the e's will remain e's.  I know that the e is overwriting the o's, but I just don't know how to fix.  MY current output is 'Helle Werld".  Again, I want "Holle, Werld". thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class E2U7
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String river = "Hello, World";
    river = river.replace("e","o");
    river = river.replace("o","e");
    System.out.print(river);
  }
}
```

Comment: Go character by character, or use a filler character for swapping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could go char by char in your String:

```
public class JavaTestiMain {
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String river = "Hello, World";
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : river.toCharArray()){
        if(c == 'e'){
            sb.append('o');
        }
        else if (c=='o'){
            sb.append('e');
        }
        else{
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
  }
}
```

Since your are a starter, a (hopefully) understandable explaination: Basically, you loop over the given String, starting with the first symbol. If it is an e, add an o to your temporary solution, if it is an o, add an e, and if it is another char, add it. At the end get the final String from your StringBuilder.
In this case, you don't Change your e's to o's ant then Change all to e's.

The advantage to the other answers is, that the intermediate symbol doesn't cause problems if they are in the start-string.

Comment: thanks but to hard for me i just started this monday

Comment: @visiontech60 as stated by the comments on my answer, **this** answer is prefered over mine.

Comment: @visiontech60 added an explaination, hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 4):

Use an intermediate symbol

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class E2U7
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String river = "Hello, World";
    river = river.replace("e","x");
    river = river.replace("o","e");
    river = river.replace("x","o");
    System.out.print(river);
  }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc6xDoIwEAbgnae4dIIEeQHj7uLE4GAcTriQYuGathAM4dnrpcqqw@VP/v8brscZD2xp7NtnjHZ6GN1AY9B7uKAe1ywD@LY@YJCYWbcwyJbXwemxu90BXecLgascwKcGp2dycAJ1JmO4hCs706pjIvuWsnJkDTaUK1KlWlTx07AY@mMWMbyb@uUDDRVPobLyWMgTTuOWbTG@AQ)

**Edit 1:**
As stated on the comments, this is **one** solution but **not the best one**, since it relies on an intermediate character that can occur on the input string. I will not update my answer since a better approach has already been posted (see @Thomas Böhm's answer).

Comment: This is not the best solution...If the string contains letter `x`.

Comment: this should be avoided as there might me 'x' in the string

Answer (score 1):

Here is a stream version of what you're trying to accomplish:

```
String result = Arrays.stream(river.split(""))
                      .map(c -> c.equals("e")? "o" : c.equals("o")?  "e" : c)
                      .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
river = river.replace("e","_");
river = river.replace("o","e");
river = river.replace("_","o");
```

Use a temporary char that is not on the input string!

Answer (score 0):

You can replace this code in main method it will work

```
 String river = "Hello, World";
 String str = river;
river = river.replaceAll("e","*");//o
river = river.replaceAll("o","#");//e
river = river.replaceAll("\\*","o").replaceAll("#","e");
System.out.print(river);
```